# Когда строка становится итерируемым объектом?

Tags: javascript, строки, циклы, объекты

На [learn.js](https://learn.javascript.ru/iterable#stroka-perebiraemyy-obekt) пишется, что строка является итерируемым объектом.

Я не совсем понимаю как это происходит. Строка - не объект, это примитивный тип данных. Может здесь имеется в виду, что строка становится итерируемым объектом, когда с ней "обращаются" как с объектом (превращается в объект-обертку)? То есть по сути for..of преобразует строку в объект-обертку, как?

Comment: Скорее тут контекст "объект" не как тип данных, а как элемент мира)) То есть дерево - объект, окружающая среда - объект (наблюдений) и т.д.  Скорее тут можно слово воспринимать как "элемент"

Comment: А я не соглашусь. Как я понимаю, при итерации примитив будет неявно преобразован в экземпляр класса String. А такое описание приводит недопониманию.

Comment: Это поведение называется boxing.
https://learn.javascript.ru/primitives-methods#primitiv-kak-obekt